# Bulk Add AD through Powershell/CSV issue

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to bulk-add users into my Active Directory, but I am getting expression errors right at the start of the script. I am not a script buff at all, so I am really out of ideas from the get go.

```
$Users = Import-Csv ".\UsersFile.csv"
foreach ($User in $Users)
{
        -OrganizationalUnit $User.OU 
        -SamAccountName $User.UserName 
        -userPassword $User.Password 
        -GivenName $User.First 
        -Initials $USer.Initial 
        -sn $User.Last 
        -Displayname $User.DisplayName
        -Description $User.Description
        -Physicaldeliveryofficename $User.Office 
        -TelephoneNumber $User.Tel
        -Mail $User.mail 
        -streetaddress $User.Street 
        -postOfficeBox $User.Postbus
        -l $User.Location 
        -st $User.Provincie 
        -postalCode $User.Postcode 
        -c $User.Land 
        -deparment $User.Department
        -Company $User.Organisatie
        -Manager $User.Manager
        -Password $User.Password -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $false 
}
```

The error log.

Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CreateUserBulk.ps1:4 char:10
+          - <<<< OrganizationalUnit $User.OU `
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (-:String) [], Parseexception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorID : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

---

After trying the link (From serv) and editing the CSV and script accordingly, getting a lot more errors now with this.

Import-Csv : Cannot open file "C:\Users\administrator\UsersFile.csv".
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Untitled3.ps1:2 char:20
+ $Users = Import-Csv <<<<  -Delimiter ";" -Path ".\UsersFile.csv"
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (:) [Import-Csv], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FileOpenFailure,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Untitled3.ps1:9 char:53
+     $FirstLetterFirstname = $UserFirstname.substring <<<< (0,1)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (substring:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

ConvertTo-SecureString : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Untitled3.ps1:11 char:195
+     New-ADUser -Name $Detailedname -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $SAM -DisplayName $Detailedname -GivenName
 $user.firstname -Surname $user.name -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString <<<<  $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Ena
bled $true -Path $OU
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSe
   cureStringCommand

---

EDIT2: Fixed, I changed the source link to it's fullness and now it works!

Comment: and what is the delimiter in your csv source file?

Comment: Added, the delimiter is  a semicolon

Comment: The first error is easy: The path to the csv is incorrect. The second error says: the variable $password is null.

Comment: Glad I could help ;) It's always the little things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating a new AD user in your script. So `-OrganizationalUnit` should be undefined and throw an error, excpet you declare them as a variable first.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path ".\UsersFile.csv"  
foreach ($User in $Users)  
{  
    $FirstLetterFirstname = $User.firstname.substring(0,1)     

    New-ADUser -Name $User.firstname + " " + $User.name 
    -SamAccountName $FirstLetterFirstName + $User.name 
    //... and so on
}
```

You can declare all variables first in the manner of `$FirstletterFirstName` and execute the `New-ADUser` command at the end of each loop, which makes it easier to read and modify later on.

The important part stays: Adding a new user is executed through the `New-ADUser` command which you are missing. You can also add the `New-ADUser` to the top of your loop, which should make your query work if there are no other syntax errors / Spelling errors in your code

//EDIT: You can find a working example at http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ed20b349-9758-4c70-adc0-19c5acfcae45

and the TechNet article for New-ADUser:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx

Comment: I tried the example script, I altered it and the CSV accordingly to test it. But it's giving me even more errors than before. Edited my first post...

Comment: This is awkward. I was at the same position you were at some time and used this very script (and still use it) to insert dummy data into my Sharepoint dev machine if I need to. My bet is, the errors come from a faulty New-ADUser command you are trying to issue